# How to assign a package to a variable in Go?

Tags: go

*First of all, the word "variable" might be wrong in the question but I assume the detailed question explains why I'm using the word "variable".*

I have two packages with different names but the exact same function(s).

Depending on the input of the user I want to use the function of a package. But instead of switching over the packages I would like to assign the package to a new function with a generic name, how to do this? And if it's not possible, why?

```
// foo/bar.go

package foo

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("hola from bar")
}
```

---

```
// baz/bar.go

package baz

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("hola from baz")
}
```

---

```
// main.go

package main

import (
    "foo"
    "baz"
)

func main() {

    thePackage := flag.String("package", "foo", "a package")

    if thePackage == "foo" {
        howToSetThis := foo // How to do this?
    } else {
        howToSetThis := baz // How to do this?
    }

    howToSetThis.Test() // execs Println from one of the two bar.go files

}
```

In JavaScript I would do something like (simplified):

```
function foo(){
  console.log("hola from foo")
}

function baz(){
  console.log("hola from baz")
}

if(somethingInput == "foo"){
  var howToSetThis = foo;
} else {
  var howToSetThis = baz;
}

howToSetThis();
```

Comment: How about using the function types instead, and choosing what function to run https://play.golang.org/p/aY3zIBRw9w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a interface in a package that requires the functions you want to have in those two packages .

```
package intfc

type Intfc interface {
    Test()
}
```

And then two structs in different packages which implements that interface

```
package foo

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {

}

func (f Foo) Test() {
    fmt.Println("hola from foo")
}
```

and

```
package baz

import "fmt"

type Baz struct {

}

func (f Baz) Test() {
    fmt.Println("hola from baz")
}
```

And then in main do something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "foo"
    "baz"
    "intfc"
    "flag"
)

func main() {

    var howToSetThis intfc.Intfc

    thePackage := flag.String("package", "foo", "a package")

    if *thePackage == "foo" {
        howToSetThis = foo.Foo{}
    } else {
        howToSetThis = baz.Baz{}
    }

    howToSetThis.Test() // execs Println from one of the two bar.go files

}
```

Comment: O, this seems to be what I need, Thanks! But now it says: `cannot refer to unexported name foo.foo`

Comment: sorry, name the struct with a capital letter to be visible outside the package: `type Foo struct {}`

Comment: Thanks, updated the question. They are now available but I now get: `howToSetThis declared and not used`... Almost there :-)

Comment: are you calling the function `howToSetThis.Test() `, because if you just assign a variable without using it the compiler will give that error.

Comment: Oh no, sorry. The example of above gives: `type foo.Foo is not an expression` and `type foo.Baz is not an expression`. I've tried `howToSetThis := foo.Foo{}` and that gives the error from above.

Comment: I made it work in the playground, you can take a look here: https://play.golang.org/p/CBDz9WW_NF

Comment: Yes! This works. Many thanks. Just one little thing I don't understand. Why: `howToSetThis = foo.Foo{}` and not `howToSetThis = foo.Foo`

Comment: Because the struct must be allocated in the memory in order to call the function associated to it. `Foo{}` is equal to `new(Foo)`

Comment: Hi @Alex, Any chance you can help with this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755892/in-golang-how-to-deal-with-unknown-variables-or-how-to-deal-with-multiple-datab Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

At compile time `import` is practically if not the first directive to get parsed.  That means whatever package name is present in the import directive will be the one used as reference in parsing everything else.

Hence you can't use a dynamic language structure like what you did in Javascript.  Cerise's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks @believesInSanta, I see your point, but it is more that I would like to have this set to like in Cerise Limón's answer. So that I later in the code always can call the same function.