# How to deal with unknown variables or How to deal with multiple databases

Tags: go

I'm working on a Go RESTful API application with multiple databases. When starting the server, the user supplies which database they would like to use.

In the application, I have **three functions** of which one handles the connection: `selectedDb.Get()`, `selectedDb.Add()`, `selectedDb.Connect()`.

If somebody selects, Mysql, it handles things for Mysql, if someone selects MongoDB it handles things for Mongo and so on.

This is how I *try* to accomplish this:

**DbInterface.go**

```
package dbinit

type Object struct {
    Uuid         string
    Object       string
    Deleted      bool
}

// The interface that all connectors should have
type Intfc interface {
    Connect() HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM
    Add(string, string, string) string
    Get(string) (Object, bool)
}
```

**MySQL.go**

```
package mysqlConnector

import (
    ...
)

type Mysql struct{}

// Connect to mysql
func (f Mysql) Connect() HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM {

    client, err = sql.Open("mysql", "yourusername:yourpassword@/yourdatabase")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())    
    }

    return client
}

// Add item to DB
func (f Mysql) Add(owner string, refType string, object string) string {
    // do stuff related to this DB

    return // a string
}

func (f Mysql) Get(Uuid string) (dbinit.Object, bool) {
    // do stuff related to this DB

    return // an object and a bool
}
```

**Mongo.go**

```
package mongoConnector

import (
    ...
)

type Mongo struct{}

// Connect to mongo
func (f Mongo) Connect() HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    client, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return client
}

// Add item to DB
func (f Mongo) Add(owner string, refType string, object string) string {
    // do stuff related to this DB

    return // a string
}

func (f Mongo) Get(Uuid string) (dbinit.Object, bool) {
    // do stuff related to this DB

    return // an object and a bool
}
```

**main.go**

```
...

var selectedDb dbinit.Intfc

commandLineInput := "mysql" // just for the example

if commandLineInput == "mysql" {
    selectedDb = mysqlConnector.Mysql{}
} else if commandLineInput == "mongo" {
    selectedDb = mongoConnector.Mongo{}
}

client := selectedDb.Connect()

// this runs everytime the API is called
api.HandlerFoobar = foobar.handlerFunction(func(params foobar.Params) middleware.Responder {

    // Here I want to add something to the selected dbinit
    selectedDb.Get(client, addStringA, addStringB, addStringC)

    return // the API response

})

...
```

**Problem statement**

When I return the client for Mysql, it doesn't work for Mongo and visa versa.

I want to connect to the database ONLY when starting the server and store the `client` inside the client variable. The problem, however, is that Mongo returns another client than Mysql does and so forth.

1. What should be in the places where I have `HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM` in the code?
2. Or do I get the Go paradigm wrong for dealing with these things?

Comment: You might be able to wrap each returned client in a struct that implements a common interface.

Comment: Are `Get`/`Add` analogous to `Select`/`Insert` in mysql? Or do they represent some *connection* managment stuff only? That is, is `Intfc` supposed to handle only the db connection (open, close, etc.) or does it also handle data storage and retrieval (insert user, select comments, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to preserve the interface with those methods, you should change a little your interface as:

**Interface:**

```golang
// The interface that all connectors should have
type Intfc interface {
    // Connect to the database, if an error occur at the moment
    // of connection, return the error
    Connect() error
    // Add returns a string, it returns an error if something occurs
    Add(string, string, string) (string, error)
    Get(string) (Object, bool)
}
```

**MySQL:**

```golang
type Mysql struct{
    conn *sql.DB // contains the connection to the DB
}

// Connect to mysql
func (f *Mysql) Connect() error {
    conn, err := sql.Open("mysql", "yourusername:yourpassword@/yourdatabase")
    if err != nil {
        return error
    }
    f.conn = conn
    return nil
}

// Add item to DB
func (f *Mysql) Add(owner string, refType string, object string) (string, error) {
    // do something
    return // a string and error
}

func (f *Mysql) Get(Uuid string) (dbinit.Object, bool) {
    // do something
    return // an object and a bool
}
```

**Mongo:**

```
type Mongo struct{
    session *mgo.Session
}

// Connect to mongo
func (f *Mongo) Connect() error {
    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        // some data
    }

    session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err != nil {
        return error
    }
    f.session = session
    return nil
}

// Add item to DB
func (f *Mongo) Add(owner string, refType string, object string) (string, error) {
    // do something
    return // a string and error (it could be nil at success)
}

func (f *Mongo) Get(Uuid string) (dbinit.Object, bool) {
    // do something
    return // an object and a bool
}
```

**Main:**

```golang
var selectedDb dbinit.Intfc

commandLineInput := "mysql"

if commandLineInput == "mysql" {
    selectedDb = &mysqlConnector.Mysql{}
} else if commandLineInput == "mongo" {
    selectedDb = &mongoConnector.Mongo{}
}

err := selectedDb.Connect()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// this runs everytime the API is called
api.HandlerFoobar = foobar.handlerFunction(func(params foobar.Params) middleware.Responder {
    data, err := selectedDb.Add(addStringA, addStringB, addStringC)
    if err != nil {
        // do something
    }

    return // the API response
})
```

But you also can remove the `Connect() error` method from `Intfc` and just use `Add` and `Get`, but you should update the packages like:

**Mysql**

```golang
// Connect to mysql, it could be any function name
func Connect() (*Mysql, error) {
    connection, err := sql.Open("mysql", "yourusername:yourpassword@/yourdatabase")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, error
    }
    return &Mysql{conn: connection}
}
```

**Mongo**

```golang
// Connect to mongo, it could be any function name
func Connect() (*Mongo, error) {
    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        // some data
    }

    s, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, error
    }
    return &Mongo{session: s}
}
```

**Main**

```golang
var selectedDb dbinit.Intfc
var err error
commandLineInput := "mysql"

if commandLineInput == "mysql" {
    selectedDb, err = mysqlConnector.Connect()
} else if commandLineInput == "mongo" {
    selectedDb, err = mongoConnector.Connect()
}

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment, instead of

```
type Intfc interface {
    Connect() HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM
    Add(string, string, string) string
    Get(string) (Object, bool)
}
```

you can use

```
type Intfc interface {
    Connect() DBClient
}
```

and

```
type DBClient interface {
    Add(string, string, string) string
    Get(string) (Object, bool)
}

type MySQLClient sql.DB
type MongoClient mgo.Session

func (f Mysql) Connect() DBCLient {

    client, err = sql.Open("mysql", "yourusername:yourpassword@/yourdatabase")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())    
    }

    return MySQLClient(client)
}

func (f Mongo) Connect() DBClient {

    info := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{hosts},
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
        Database: database,
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    }

    client, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(info)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return MongoClient(client)
}

func (s *MySQLClient) Add(...) {
    // ...
}

func (s *MongoClient) Add(...) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for sharing, but how would I connect now?

Comment: You connect the same way you did in your original question. The value returned in now a `DBClient` instead of a client of type specific to the database. That client has methods to do the other DB operations

Comment: Instead of `selectedDb.Get(client, addStringA, addStringB, addStringC)`, you call `client.Get(addStringA, addStringB, addStringC)`.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get this to work. Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: this returns: `cannot use mysqlConnector.Mysql literal (type mysqlConnector.Mysql) as type dbinit.Intfc in assignment:
    mysqlConnector.Mysql does not implement dbinit.Intfc (wrong type for Connect method)
        have Connect() mysqlConnector.MySQLClient
        want Connect() dbinit.DBClient`

Comment: just change the return type of the `Connect` method on your `Mysql` implementation, from `func (Mysql) Connect() MySQLClient {...` to `func (Mysql) Connect() dbinit.DBClient {...`

Comment: The main idea divide your Intfc to 2 level. First - MySqlIntfc and MgoIntfc will provide only method Add and Get - and both satified interface Intfc. And second level provides only functions Connect (better names will be NewMySqlIntfc and NewMgoIntfc) that return Intfc. It allows client to Get/Add without knowlegde of what interface is used.

Comment: Thanks all, but it doesn't seem to work. Started a bounty to maybe get some other answers

Answer (score 1):

I think, that interface Intfc (or better name DbIntfc) should have only methods Get and Add.

And it should exist another function - but not a part of DbIntfc, that returns DbIntfc - that connects to MySql or MongoDb. Let's look:

```
    type MySqlDbIntfc struct{
       db *Sql.DB
    }

    // Connect to mysql
    func NewMySqlDbIntfc() (DbIntfc,error) {
        // Please do not prefer panic in such abstract methods
        client, err := sql.Open("mysql", "yourusername:yourpassword@/yourdatabase")
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return &MySqlDbIntfc{client}, nil
    }

    func (mySqlDb *MySqlDbIntfc) Get(Uuid string) (dbinit.Object, error) {
      var obj dbinit.Object
      err := mySqlDb.db.QueryRow("SELECT uuid, object, deleted FROM myTable WHERE uuid=?", Uuid).Scan(&obj.Uuid, &obj.Object, &obj.Deleted)
      if err != nil {
        return dbinit.Object{}, err
      }
      return obj, nil
    }
```

And implemention NewMgoDbIntfc should be easy, including methods NewMgoDbIntfc.Add/Get.

And decision whether use NewMySqlDbIntfc or NewMgoDbIntfc should also be easy.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What should be in the places where I have HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM in the code?

As you can see from [the source](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2/session.go#L415) that the `DialWithInfo()` return `error` and `*Session` from `mgo` package and that is a `struct`. so you can replace your **HERE_LIES_MY_PROBLEM** with `*mgo.Session`

> 2. do I get the Go paradigm wrong for dealing with these things?

As far as the idiomatic to connect with multiple databases there are many opinion I think. And here is some of my thought to connect with mongo and redis :

```
var logger *log.Logger

func init() {
    logger = log.New(os.Stderr,
        "Database :: ",
        log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
}

//we create different types of databse connection here.
func SystemConnection() map[string]interface{} {
    listConnection := make(map[string]interface{})
    var err error
    // create redis connection
    redisConn := RedisHost{
        Address:  "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    }

    redisConnection, err := redisConn.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //create mongodb connection
    mongo := MongoHost{
        Host: "localhost",
        Port: "27017",
    }
    mongoConnection := mongo.Connect()

    listConnection["redis"] = redisConnection
    listConnection["mongodb"] = mongoConnection
    return listConnection
}

func GetMongo() *mgo.Session {
    //create mongodb connection
    mongo := MongoHost{
        Host: "localhost",
        Port: "27017",
    }
    mongoConnection := mongo.Connect()

    return mongoConnection
}
```

you can see the source [from here](https://github.com/Gujarats/API-Golang/tree/master/database)

To use above code you can call the `SystemConnection()` on your `init()` in your main program. like this :

```
func init(){
    listConnection := database.SystemConnection()

    //getting redis connection convert it from interface to *redisClient.
    redisConn := listConnection["redis"].(*redis.Client)

    // get postgre connection.
    mongoConn := listConnection["mongodb"].(*mgo.Session)

}
```

Again this approach is my opinion there are others that might be suit with yours.